# Sync outlook calendar with the calendar app

Tags: release-loki, calendar

This might be a silly question with an easy solution, but I've yet to find it.
I'm trying to set up my outlook calendar (from uni, has my classes and stuff) to sync with the calendar app on 0.4.1loki. I have it working great on my smartphone with IMAP, but no luck on my computer. Any ideas?
Thanks,
Ted

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I do not believe that is currently possible, Calendar doesn't currently support Exchange although there was some work on that in pantheon accounts, although I don't believe that works currently. Outlook supports publishing the calendar on a webdav server, however it does that without authentication which Calendar doesn't currently support, hopefully support for that can be added soon.

Relevant GitHub issues: [Outlook support](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/20), [Exchange support](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/41), [ics sync](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/75), [read only calendar support](https://github.com/elementary/calendar/issues/104)